# UITableViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am wondering whether someone has had similar problem that I am experimented lately.

Let me describe you a little bit further about my issue. I have got a UITableViewController where I have designed a set of custom UITableViewCell in the IB. Each UITableViewCell has got different elements like a UIButton, UITextField and UILabel, etc. Obviously, each UITableViewCell has a different identifier.

Once defined all my UITableViewCells, next step is to instantiate the cell on tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. What I do in this method is depending on section and row, I instantiate the different UITableViewCells by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:.

Everything seems to work perfectly and correctly created on the table, but the problem arrives when I scroll down. At the very top, I have got a UITableViewCell with a UIButton that I have specified with a concrete action to perform when it is clicked. Scrolling down, there are a couple of UITableViewCells with the same format (an UIButton inside with different actions specified).

The problem is, when a click the first button from the bottom side, this button performs the first action that I have defined on the very top UIButton and its own action.

It seems that when uitableviewdelegate creates new cells or reuse them, it nests functionalities from other indexPath instead of the specified indexPath....

Hope that I have explained myself properly.

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

NSLog(@"indexpath value is: %@", indexPath);

if (indexPath.section == 0)
    cell = [self buildSection_0:tableView getIndexPath:indexPath];
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    cell = [self buildSection_1:tableView getIndexPath:indexPath];
else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    cell = [self buildSection_2:tableView getIndexPath:indexPath];
else if (indexPath.section == 3)
    cell = [self buildSection_3:tableView getIndexPath:indexPath];
else if (indexPath.section == 4)
    cell = [self buildSection_4:tableView getIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)buildSection_0:(UITableView *)tableView getIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *identifier;
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (indexPath.row == 0){
    identifier = @"headerCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1){
    identifier = @"buttonCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3001];
    [button setTitle:@"Scan" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(scan) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)buildSection_3:(UITableView *)tableView getIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *identifier;
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (indexPath.row == [[job jobLocations] count]) { // Adding button insert more Locations
    identifier = @"buttonCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3001];
    [button setTitle:@"Add Location" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(newLocation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else{ // Showing different Locations
    identifier = @"locationCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3007];
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:3008];

    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location #%ld", (long)indexPath.row + 1]];
    [textField setText:[[[job jobLocations] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] locationType]];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: post code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` will reuse cells that are no longer visible, you may want to implement `prepareForReuse` on your cell, or reset it after you dequeue it.

[EDIT]

Seeing you added your code, you should remove previous target/actions from the button before adding the new ones, as the old one will still be there if a cell is being reused:

```
[button removeTarget:self action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:...
```

Comment: It works perfectly your advise. Thank you very much. But, in case this behaviour happened to any other cell or element, i guess the idea would be to keep the values stored somewhere and each time I want to draw the different cells or element, bring up this information. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to the button that corresponds to the `indexPath.row`. Then in your button action method, you can determine which button was clicked by looking at the `(UIButton *)sender`'s tag.